# Wanting to use Address or Match as input for a function

Tags: excel, google-sheets

How can I use returned values from functions as inputs?

For example ADDRESS could return A2.

I want to then lets say use match, in the range A1:A2, and use A1:ADDRESS()?

Is this possible?

---

To go into more detail I have a table as so:

| 0 | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Forenames | Surnames |
| 2 | James | Sanchez |
| 3 |  | Craven |
| 4 | Martin | Boots |

In another table I want to find all forenames, of people with the surname Craven. To do that I search for "Craven", as an INDEX to get the value 3. Then I use this to make the ADDRESS A3. From there I have a function to find the last word in a list, but I need to put the range as A1:A3 (The top to the last value), as looking up A3 would return a blank.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You need to use `INDIRECT()` function in this case. I think there may some other way to achieve your output. Can you please explain little more what are you actually trying to do.

Comment: The following function is the one to find the last non-empty value in a range.


=INDEX( FILTER( A1:A5 , NOT( ISBLANK( A1:A5 ) ) ) , ROWS( FILTER( A1:A5 , NOT( ISBLANK( A1:A5 ) ) ) ) )


I want to replace the value of A5 in this equation with the result from the address of, in the previous example, A3, which is gotten from an index by searching through column B for a certain entry.

The surname searched up can be different.

The issue with using INDIRECT is that it would return an empty value, as A3 is BLANK, so therefore it would search between A1:BLANK would it not?

Comment: So, you only want non empty last value from that range? Suppose you are searching for `Craven` in column B then return non empty last value from `A1:A3` which is `James` as `A3` is empty.

Comment: Are you doing it in Excel or google sheet?

Comment: I think you are going about this wrong.  A range can be defined as`A1:INDEX(A:A, MATCH( "Craven", B:B, 0)`  .  No need for ADDRESS or INDIRECT

Answer (score 1):

go for:

```
=INDIRECT("A1:"&ADDRESS(2, 1))
```

which translates as: A1:A2